# jQueryUI Tooltip - Text without spaces overlaps tooltip container

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a page in my web application that has numerous controls that display a `jQueryUI` tooltip when hovered. This works great for tooltips that contain standard text with spaces.

However when the tooltip text does not contain spaces, such as a file path or a database field name, the text overlaps the tooltip container.

How can I get force the text to wrap onto another line like the standard tooltip does?

Thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3uj4wnbe/3/)

**Code**

```
$('.jQueryTooltip').tooltip();

<p>
  <span title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.">Standard tooltip with spaces</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span title="Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat">Standard tooltip without spaces</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="jQueryTooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.">jQuery tooltip with spaces</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="jQueryTooltip" title="Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat">jQuery tooltip with spaces</span>
</p>
```

Comment: apply `span {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this style:

```
 .ui-tooltip {
     word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```